# Bokeh get values from CustomJS (change values in data source)

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I have modified [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-selections).
What I want- eventually- is a way to get the datapoints selected in a graph and modifiy them in the python code. Thus I added a function here that should return the values from the second graph (thats what the button is for). However, if I select the points, they are plotted correctly, but the data source is not changed (the button click provides {'X':[],'Y':[]}. How do I write back from JS to the python bokeh data source? Isn't  the s2.change.emit() or a s2.trigger('change') supposed to do this? I also tried the latter but its not working.

```
from random import random

from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.io import curdoc


x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]

s1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
p1 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, tools="lasso_select", title="Select Here")
p1.circle('x', 'y', source=s1, alpha=0.6)

s2 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))
p2 = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400, x_range=(0, 1), y_range=(0, 1),
            tools="", title="Watch Here")
p2.circle('x', 'y', source=s2, alpha=0.6)

s1.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(args=dict(s1=s1, s2=s2), code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        var d1 = s1.data;
        var d2 = s2.data;
        d2['x'] = []
        d2['y'] = []
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            d2['x'].push(d1['x'][inds[i]])
            d2['y'].push(d1['y'][inds[i]])
        }
        s2.change.emit();
    """)
)
def get_values():
    global s2
    print(s2.data)     

button = Button(label="Get selected set")
button.on_click(get_values)


layout = row(p1, p2,button)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "my dashboard"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will display the updated source data from the second plot when the button is clicked. Run it with: `bokeh serve --show app.py`

```
from random import random
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Row
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button

x = [random() for x in range(500)]
y = [random() for y in range(500)]

s1 = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = x, y = y))
p1 = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400, tools = "lasso_select", title = "Select Here")
p1.circle('x', 'y', source = s1, alpha = 0.6)

s2 = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(x = [], y = []))
p2 = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400, x_range = (0, 1), y_range = (0, 1), tools = "", title = "Watch Here")
p2.circle('x', 'y', source = s2, alpha = 0.6)

s1.selected.js_on_change('indices', CustomJS(args = dict(s1 = s1, s2 = s2), code = """
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        var d1 = s1.data;
        d2 = {'x': [], 'y': []}
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            d2['x'].push(d1['x'][inds[i]])
            d2['y'].push(d1['y'][inds[i]])
        }
        s2.data = d2  """))

def get_values():
    print(s2.data)

button = Button(label = "Get selected set")
button.on_click(get_values)

curdoc().add_root(Row(p1, p2, button))
```

The source data is not updated in your example because there is no mechanism in JS to detect the push changes. Only assigning a new object to `source.data` can be detected. Once the change is detected the data between BokehJS and Python models can be synchronised.

Comment: Great, thx! Can you briefly describe what the s2.change.emit() is needed for? It seems like it is not required any more.

Comment: It is used when you modify the `source.data` directly via reference (without replacing the entire source.data object with a new one) Please note that your original example was using a reference to the existing source.data (so not replacing it with a new object)